# Plone 4 - get type of authenticated user

Tags: ldap, plone, plone-4.x

I have users registered on the website and users that are logging in using an external account (plone.app.ldap is used).

How can I get the type of logged in user?

```
membership = getToolByName(self.context, 'portal_membership')
authenticated_user = membership.getAuthenticatedMember()

(Pdb) authenticated_user
<MemberData at /mywebsite/portal_memberdata/myuserid used for /mywebsite/acl_users>
```

I have the logged in user, but no idea how to find how it is registered.
(It seems `membership_tool.listMembers()` gives me the registered users list. Maybe I can use this...)

My goal is to send the type of account to Google Analytics as custom dimension in a custom event and creating some nice reports (the type of account will be a filter for the results).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal of the PAS service is exactly your problem :-)

It's called pluggable auth service. This means you can register several services and the PAS gives you a single entry point to perform manipulations and queries.
This means you usually don't have to care about whether the user is a plone user or ldap user.

AFAIK the only possible way is to ask the ldap plugin directly:

ldap: The id of your AD/LDAP plugin

plone: Your plone site

```
>>> membership = getToolByName(plone, 'portal_membership')
>>> authenticated_user = membership.getAuthenticatedMember()

>>> search = plone.acl_users.ldap.acl_users.searchUsers
<bound method LDAPUserFolder.searchUsers of <LDAPUserFolder at /fd/acl_users/ldap/acl_users>>

>>> search(uid=authenticated_user.getId())
[{'dn': 'cn=Test USER,ou=Users, ...', 'uid': 'test.user', 'sn': 'Test', 'mail': 't.user@email.com', 'givenName': 'USER', 'cn': 'Test User'}]
```

The search result depends on your ad/ldap configuration.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. :)

`search = plone.acl_users.get("ldap-plugin").acl_users.searchUsers` in my case.

Comment: Mathias answer is right but IIRC users returned by this plugin is also giving information about it's origin somewwhere in the props.
Unluckily this is not a standard behavior.

Comment: I'm not aware of that. This would be obviously the better soution, since it does not required a second, possible request to the ldap.